# Clickonce Fails

Tags: .net, iis, http-status-code-404, clickonce

I'm trying to install a ClickOnce application using web deployment. Publish folder Location to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\ and Installation Folder URL as http://localhost/website1/MyApp/. When I publish I get "Warning Files could not be downloaded from http://computer-name/website1/MyApp. If I go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\ the MyApp.application runs without issues but the setup.exe. Using window.location.href = http://computer-name/website1/MyApp.application fails with a 404 error

Can someone help?

Comment: What's the site binding you use? Wrong bindings can lead to such 404 https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Type: http, Hostname:computer-name, and port: 80

Comment: Based on the limited info you wrote, it is more likely that http://computer-name/MyApp might work.

Comment: I tried that and I get a 403 error

Comment: What information do you need? I have been looking at this for hours